# WordPress Boilerplat Plugin Development - Display Saved Field Data

Tags: wordpress, boilerplate

I'm trying to learn how to do a wordpress plugin, and I've taken the boilerplate path.

I have a file structure like:

[image]

I have followed some tutorials to get my data saving in the admin backend:

[image]

I now want to display these values in the front end, when a shortcode is entered.

So, the next bit is where I am unsure if I am going wrong, is I am opening the file **horse-exchange.php** in the root of the plugin folder and I am adding the following code:

```
    function horse_odds_shortcode() {



    return 'display plugin data here<br>';

//DISPLA VALUES FROM BACKEND

}
add_shortcode('horse_odds', 'horse_odds_shortcode');
```

Now, if I create a page and type [horse_odds], it displays 'display plugin data here'.

However, what I want to display is the betfair affiliate id and the smarkets affiliate id from the admin backend.

I have tried adding this code in the shortcode function above

```
function horse_odds_shortcode() {

$options = get_option($this->plugin_name);

        // Cleanup
        $betfair_show = $options['betfair_show'];
        $betfair_username = $options['betfair_username'];
        $betfair_password = $options['betfair_password'];
        $betfair_affiliate_id = $options['betfair_affiliate_id'];
        $smarkets_show = $options['smarkets_show'];
        $smarkets_affiliate_id = $options['smarkets_affiliate_id'];


echo $smarkets_affiliate_id;
    return 'display plugin data here<br>';

//DISPLA VALUES FROM BACKEND

}
add_shortcode('horse_odds', 'horse_odds_shortcode');
```

However, the code doesnt work. Does anyone have an idea where I am going wrong?

Here is my plugin code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ano5hg7twtp21sd/horse-exchange.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Shortcodes in WP always *return* data. So, in your first example:

```
function horse_odds_shortcode() {
    return 'display plugin data here<br>';
}
```

This works, because the shortcode is returning the string for the shortcode to display. To get the shortcode to display your saved data:

```
function horse_odds_shortcode() {
    $options = get_option($this->plugin_name);

    // Cleanup
    $betfair_show = $options['betfair_show'];
    $betfair_username = $options['betfair_username'];
    $betfair_password = $options['betfair_password'];
    $betfair_affiliate_id = $options['betfair_affiliate_id'];
    $smarkets_show = $options['smarkets_show'];
    $smarkets_affiliate_id = $options['smarkets_affiliate_id'];

    return $smarkets_affiliate_id;
}
```

If you want to show more data, maybe wrapped with HTML output, then use output buffers:

```
function horse_odds_shortcode() {
    $options = get_option($this->plugin_name);

    // Cleanup
    $betfair_show = $options['betfair_show'];
    $betfair_username = $options['betfair_username'];
    $betfair_password = $options['betfair_password'];
    $betfair_affiliate_id = $options['betfair_affiliate_id'];
    $smarkets_show = $options['smarkets_show'];
    $smarkets_affiliate_id = $options['smarkets_affiliate_id'];

    ob_start();

    ?>

    <p>
        Welcome back, <?php echo $betfair_username; ?>! Your Betfair affiliate ID is:
    </p>

    <div class="betfair-id">
        <strong>
            <?php echo $betfair_affiliate_id; ?>
        </strong>
    </div>

    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Hi, really appreciate the response. However, it is still showing the same issue: http://prntscr.com/ksapus the page stops loading.

Comment: @BCLtd No idea what I'm looking at here. When you say 'the page stops loading' - That sounds like there's an error elsewhere. I have no idea about any of what your plugin is doing or how it's structured, but check the source code of your page for any fatal errors and/or the PHP error log on your server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look - is that definitely the correct page to add this code? this was my next question

Comment: @BCLtd When you say the correct page, do you mean the correct file to add your shortcode function? It doesn't really matter where it is within a plugin, as long as it's accessible. The other crucial thing is that you're using `$this` - `$options = get_option($this->plugin_name)` - which is class-specific. If your function is outside of the class scope, then `$this` will almost certainly be undefined.

Comment: Thanks again - sorry really struggling with getting to grips with it. I appreciate your patience, I'll have a go